# facing an error during installing mumps on cygwin?

Tags: gcc, cygwin, mumps

trying to install mumps on my windows laptop, followed instructions to setup cygwin first and install mumps through it....now facing this error updon running ./BuildMumpsWithNativeClientServer.script in cygwin terminal

```
config.status: creating include/mumpsc/config.h
Now run "make" followed by "make install"
gcc -w -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -O3 -DMUMPS_SYM -Iinclude/  -finline-functions  -w -DMUMPS_SYM  -Iinclude/ -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -O3  -lgmp   -c -o mumps.o mumps.c
gcc -w -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -O3 -DMUMPS_SYM -Iinclude/  -finline-functions  -w -DMUMPS_SYM  -Iinclude/ -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -O3  -lgmp   -c -o parse.o parse.c
gcc -w -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -O3 -DMUMPS_SYM -Iinclude/  -finline-functions  -w -DMUMPS_SYM  -Iinclude/ -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -O3  -lgmp   -c -o sys1.o sys1.c
g++  -w -DMUMPS_SYM  -Iinclude/ -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -O3  -lgmp   -c -o arith.o arith.cpp
sys1.c:804:1: error: conflicting types for ‘itoa’
 itoa (val, str, rad)
 ^~~~
In file included from sys1.c:51:0:
/usr/include/stdlib.h:224:8: note: previous declaration of ‘itoa’ was here
 char * itoa (int, char *, int);
        ^~~~
make: *** [<builtin>: sys1.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
arith.cpp: In function ‘void mps_exp10(char*, char*)’:
arith.cpp:855:15: error: ‘exp10’ was not declared in this scope
     double aa=exp10(strtod(a,NULL));
               ^~~~~
arith.cpp:855:15: note: suggested alternative: ‘expx’
     double aa=exp10(strtod(a,NULL));
               ^~~~~
               expx
make: *** [<builtin>: arith.o] Error 1
```

Comment: Can you tell us where you got this source code to compile?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to give a non-answer that (I hope) will help you achieve your ultimate goal of installing a MUMPS build on your Windows laptop.  Because you're running "BuildMumpsWithNativeClientServer.script", I'm guessing you're trying to install Kevin O'Kane's [version of MUMPS](https://www.cs.uni.edu/~okane/source/MUMPS-MDH/index%20(copy).html).  You might want to switch to a production-ready MUMPS build like [Intersystems Cache](https://download.intersystems.com/download/login.csp), [GT.M](http://neuro.debian.net/pkgs/fis-gtm.html), or [YottaDB](https://yottadb.com/).

If you use Intersystems Cache, it will install natively on Windows.  If you use GT.M or it's fork, YottaDB, they install cleanly on most Linux distros, but not as native Windows apps.  The painless option is to install [Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) and a linux distro on your laptop.  I recommend Ubuntu 18.04 as a Linux distro, since it's the most recent long-term support linux distro that's available in the [Windows store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/ubuntu-1804-lts/9n9tngvndl3q).
Once you have linux installed via WSL on your Windows box, installing GT.M only takes a single command:  `sudo apt install fis-gtm`

I know this isn't exactly answering the question you asked, but I'm hoping it gets you the result you really want.  Good luck!